# Move the camera with the mouse?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I have a camera and I want to move it with the mouse and also move a character, but when I try to move the character it moves to another. I don't know how to explain better. XD. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on an object to select it. If you want to select more than one object <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click the additional objects. Pressing <kbd>G</kbd> will allow you to then move the object(s). If you want to constrain the movement to an axis press the <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> key after pressing <kbd>G</kbd>.